# Get durations from list of checkin dates

Tags: mysql, database, date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of checkin dates for one user.
How can I calculate duration between consecutives checkin and checkout.
If not checkout found, leave the duration as 0

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| ID | isCheckIn |     DateChecked     |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| 1  |     1     | 2019-10-08 10:22:15 | 
| 2  |     0     | 2019-10-08 10:24:30 | 
| 3  |     1     | 2019-10-08 10:27:01 | 
| 4  |     1     | 2019-10-08 10:31:44 | 
| 5  |     0     | 2019-10-08 10:50:56 | 
| 6  |     1     | 2019-10-09 09:24:09 | 
| 7  |     0     | 2019-10-09 09:35:59 | 
| 8  |     1     | 2019-10-09 10:04:26 | 
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

And I'm expecting something like this (duration in minutes)...

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|      CheckIn        |       CheckOut      | Duration |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2019-10-08 10:22:15 | 2019-10-08 10:24:30 |    2     |
| 2019-10-08 10:27:01 |                     |    0     |
| 2019-10-08 10:31:44 | 2019-10-08 10:50:56 |    19    |
| 2019-10-09 09:24:09 | 2019-10-09 09:35:59 |    11    |
| 2019-10-09 10:04:26 |                     |    0     |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I solved it getting a list, traversing it,creating couple of dates and calculating the time difference, but I prefer do more at server side.
Any suggestions, please? Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Which version of mysql are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can address this with `lead()`:

```
select
    DateChecked CheckIn,
    case 
        when leadIsCheckIn = 0 then leadDateChecked 
    end CheckOut,
    case 
        when leadIsCheckIn = 0 then timestampdiff(minute, DateChecked, leadDateChecked) 
        else 0 
    end Duration
from (
    select
        DateChecked,
        isCheckIn ,
        lead(DateChecked) over(order by DateChecked) leadDateChecked,
        lead(isCheckIn) over(order by DateChecked) leadIsCheckIn
    from mytable
) x
where isCheckIn = 1
order by DateChecked
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgVBy59mPN5d9LrXkGd93j/0)**:

```
| CheckIn             | CheckOut            | Duration |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | -------- |
| 2019-10-08 10:22:15 | 2019-10-08 10:24:30 | 2        |
| 2019-10-08 10:27:01 |                     | 0        |
| 2019-10-08 10:31:44 | 2019-10-08 10:50:56 | 19       |
| 2019-10-09 09:24:09 | 2019-10-09 09:35:59 | 11       |
| 2019-10-09 10:04:26 |                     | 0        |
```

---

In earlier versions, you can emulate `lead()` with a self-`left join` and a `not exists` condition on a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.DateChecked CheckIn,
    tlead.DateChecked CheckOut,
    coalesce(timestampdiff(minute, t.DateChecked, tlead.DateChecked), 0) Duration
from mytable t
left join mytable tlead
    on tlead.DateChecked > t.DateChecked
    and tlead.isCheckIn = 0
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.DateChecked > t.DateChecked 
            and t1.DateChecked < tlead.DateChecked
    )
where t.isCheckIn = 1
order by t.DateChecked
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgVBy59mPN5d9LrXkGd93j/1)**: same results as above.

Comment: Excelent Answer!!!! I changed the field and database names with real and everything works like a charm!!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome @SilverLora! Glad that it worked fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 5.7 Works

```
SELECT 
  MIN(`DateChecked`) CheckIn
  , MAX(`DateChecked`) CheckOut
  ,timestampdiff(MINUTE,MIN(`DateChecked`), MAX(`DateChecked`)) duration
FROM
  (SELECT 
  `DateChecked`,
  if (isCheckIn = 1,@group1 := @group1  + 1,@group1 := @group1 ) group1
  FROM
    duration, (SELECT @group1 := 0) g
  ORDER BY `DateChecked` ASC
) t1
GROUP by group1
ORDER BY CheckIn;
```

The result is then

```
CheckIn                 CheckOut                duration
2019-10-08 10:22:15     2019-10-08 10:24:30     2
2019-10-08 10:27:01     2019-10-08 10:27:01     0
2019-10-08 10:31:44     2019-10-08 10:50:56     19
2019-10-09 09:24:09     2019-10-09 09:35:59     11
2019-10-09 10:04:26     2019-10-09 10:04:26     0
```

see example here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=442c13184b01af2b6e079b80815046fb

Comment: This kind of solution normally requires an ORDER BY clause

Comment: Adapted now with order by